# How much space does Aviary and CreativeSDK add to my app size?

Tags: ios, aviary, adobecreativesdk

Question is simple how much space does these frameworks add to an app size?

https://www.aviary.com/
https://creativesdk.adobe.com/

Answer (score 2):

**I tested this here are the results:**

- My app size: 16.5mb
- App size with AdobeCreativeSDK: 31.0mb
- App size with AdobeCreativeSDK + CreativeSDKImageEditing(Aviary): 37.8
- App size with AviarySDK: 23.2mb

**So the sizes of**

- AviarySDK: 6.7mb
- CreativeSDKImageEditing: 6.8mb
- AdobeCreativeSDK: 14.5mb

So the core image editing framework parts are roughly the same size. However there this little catch:

> The Image component is part of the larger Creative SDK and depends on
>   the Foundation SDK. Please see the Creative SDK Getting Started guide
>   to learn about setting your project up for the Creative SDK.
>   https://creativesdk.adobe.com/docs/ios/#/articles/imageediting/index.html

Answer (score 1):

The only way to know for sure is to try it. Measure the size of the .ipa files (these are already compressed) before and after you add the frameworks.

It might be that depending on which part of the frameworks you actually use, the linker might strip away a lot of unused code.

Comment: How about installing on device and checking its size from settings? Does that give the same accuracy?

Comment: That is maybe even better - in the end, that is what matters to the user.